# Chrome Download Tag Does Not Download FIle

Tags: download, ftp, srt

I have problem that i want when i click on SRT on ma web page to download file...but problem is that all my files are shared throught ftp server not http so if i use http it download file, if i put in url source ftp then it opens file in chrome browser and does not download it. How can i force to download file from ftp link?

Here is HTML code:

```
<a href="ftp://myserverip/myfile.srt" download>SRT</a>
```

What i need to do so that my file is automatically downloaded when i press SRT?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a user to the link like this:

```
<a href="links:pass@ftp://myserverip/myfile.srt" download>SRT</a>
```

-- https://www.exavault.com/blog/linking-directly-to-files-in-your-ftp-account/

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks..i try adding the user and pass but it opens file, it does not download it....